# The $257^{\text{th}}$ derivative of $e^{-t} \sin t$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How to find the $257^{\text{th}}$ derivative of $e^{-t} \sin t$.

I got the wrong values in the end. Not very sure how to go on after calculating $2^{\large\frac{257}{2}}e^{\large\frac{3i}{4}}$.

Comment: Write $$\sin t = \frac{1}{2i}(e^{it} - e^{-it})$$ to get a sum of two pure exponentials.

Comment: Factor out the $\frac{1}{2i}$. You then have $\exp(t(-1+i))+\exp(t(-1-i))$. Then derivate.

Comment: The Maple code $$diff(exp(-t)*sin(t),t$257) $$ outputs $$-340282366920938463463374607431768211456\,{{\rm e}^{-t}}\sin \left( t
 \right) +340282366920938463463374607431768211456\,{{\rm e}^{-t}}\cos
 \left( t \right) .
 $$

Comment: The Maple code $$diff(exp(-t)*sin(t), t$n) $$ produces $${{\rm e}^{-t}}{2}^{n/2}\sin \left( t+3/4\,n\pi  \right) .$$

Answer (score 5):

\begin{align}
e^{-t}\sin t & = \Im\left[e^{(i - 1)t}\right]\\
\dfrac{d^{257}}{dt^{257}} e^{-t}\sin t & = \Im\left[ (i - 1)^{257}e^{(i-1)t} \right]\\
& = \Im\left[ 2^{257/2} \left(\dfrac{i - 1}{\sqrt 2}\right)^{257}  e^{(i - 1)t}\right]\\
& = \Im\left[ 2^{257/2} \left(- \cos \dfrac{\pi}{4} + i \sin \dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)^{257}e^{it}e^{-t}\right]\\
& = \Im\left[ -2^{257/2} e^{-t} \left(\cos \dfrac{257\pi}{4} - i \sin \dfrac{257\pi}{4}\right) (\cos t + i \sin t) \right]
\end{align}

Multiplying, and extracting the imaginary part:
\begin{align}
\dfrac{d^{257}}{dt^{257}} e^{-t}\sin t & = -2^{128}\sqrt{2}e^{-t}\left(\cos \dfrac{257\pi}{4}\sin t - \sin\dfrac{257\pi}{4}\cos t \right)\\
& = -2^{128}\sqrt{2}e^{-t}\sin \left( t - \dfrac{257\pi}{4} \right)\\
& = -2^{128}\sqrt{2}e^{-t}\sin \left( t - \dfrac{\pi}{4} - 64\pi\right)\\
& = 2^{128}\sqrt{2}e^{-t}\sin \left(\dfrac{\pi}{4} -t\right)\\
& = \boxed{2^{128}e^{-t}(\cos t - \sin t)}
\end{align}

Comment: The final form here can still be substantially simplified using the periodicity of sin() and the addition formula.

Comment: Ah yes, forgot that. Updated the answer by using periodicity (and absorbing the minus). Thanks!

Comment: De nada!  (It might also be worth noting that the final answer can also be written as $2^{128} e^{-t} (\cos t-\sin t)$; both are equivalent.)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Of course, I should've paid more attention to that ugly little $\sqrt 2$. It shouldn't be there, I see it now!

Answer (score 2):

From $f(t)=e^{-t}\sin(t)$, differentiate twice to get $f^{''}(t)={-2}\ e^{-t}\cos(t)$. From $g(t)=e^{-t}\cos(t)$, differentiate twice to get $g^{''}(t)={2}\ e^{-t}\sin(t)$ and hence because $f^{''}(t)={-2}\ g(t)$ it follow that  $f^{iv}(t)={-4}\ e^{-t}\sin(t) = -4 f(t)$.
Iterating this 64 times we get

$$\dfrac{d^{256}}{dt^{256}}f(t)=(-4)^{64}f(t)$$

Differentiating one more time gives the answer:
\begin{align}
\dfrac{d^{257}}{dt^{257}}f(t)&=2^{128}f^{'}(t) \\
&= 2^{128}e^{-t}(\cos(t)-\sin(t)) \\
&= 2^{128}\sqrt{2}e^{-t}\cos(t+{\pi\over 4})\\
&=2^{128}\sqrt{2}e^{-t}\sin (\dfrac{\pi}{4} -t) \ 
\end{align}

The last line follows because $ \sin(\dfrac{\pi}{2} -t) = \cos(t)$.